# Loaded ATI Driver and now all I have is the desktop. How do I get everything back?

Tags: drivers, 13.04, ati

I am running 13.04 and decided to upgrade from the onboard video on my motherboard to a new ATI HD6570 card. I downloaded the latest drivers from AMD and installed them and switched the BIOS to default to the PCIe card. Ubuntu loads, but all I get is the desktop with my single icon for Steam, nothing else. The bar of icons and the launcher on the left are gone as is the bar at the top.

Any ideas how to get everything back?

Answer (score 0):

I do not have 13.04, but have you checked the Display settings?

Probably the detected resolution is incorrect.
You could right click on the desktop -> Check Desktop Background -> All Settings -> Displays

What happens when you press the ALT or the Window Button?

In case you haven't seen it, here is more info:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI

Answer (score 0):

Latest stable driver from AMD is not compatible with the last version of Ubuntu with the latest version of the Xorg Server. Download the latest beta driver which is compatible with Ubuntu 13.04:

http://www2.ati.com/drivers/beta/amd-driver-installer-catalyst-13-6-beta-x86.x86_64.zip